# Shell script to capture the updated part in a file

Tags: linux, bash

file 1

```
23
1030042388
0
1.000000000000000
739203
0.041035795614451
754163
0.010276519532845
827907
0.147827256904898
2961752
0.017365353262416
3006283
```

The above file gets updated as

file1

```
23
1030042388
0
1.000000000000000
739203
0.041035795614451
754163
0.007314889610240
130695515
0.010276519532845
827907
0.147827256904898
2961752
0.017365353262416
3006283
0.000185740873681
13483011
0.028083838182834
13497795
0.011287502580049
13512752
0.219960404756292
13512755
```

Note updation can happen any where in the file, and numbers/lines should not be sorted
i need to capture only the update part in to other file

file 3

```
0.007314889610240
130695515
0.000185740873681
13483011
0.028083838182834
13497795
0.011287502580049
13512752
0.219960404756292
13512755
```

Could you please help me in this
Thanks

Comment: if you're going to do this sort of processing at any sort of scale beyond the 20 lines of data you've included, seems like shell is the wrong tool. maybe look at databases? Else use existing utils `diff` or `comm` (when keeping an original version of your file to perform the diff on). You're expected to include an attempt to solve your problem here on S.O., its not a free coding service. Good luck.

Comment: Do you save a copy of the file before each update?

Answer (score 4):

Using `comm`:

```
% comm -13 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)

0.000185740873681
0.007314889610240
0.011287502580049
0.028083838182834
0.219960404756292
130695515
13483011
13497795
13512752
13512755
```

Comment: This is ok only if they keep a copy of the "old" file every time they change it. Is this the case? Please note there's **no** file2 in the original question...

Comment: @mauro I am assuming the second `file1` is a typo otherwise the question needs to be rephrased to be clearer..